# sql query to get specific row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 5 tables for a sample call center system

Tables are

- Employee (ID - Name)
- Number (ID - Number)
- Call_Log (ID - EmployeeID - Number_ID - Call_Status)
- Invoice (ID - Call_Log - EmployeeID - Date)
- Invoice_Details (ID - InvoiceID - ProductName)

I have two types of employee

1. First one make the call to tell customer new offer then save call data in `Call_Log` table
2. Second type of employee create the invoice based on call status (if customer would like to buy some products, first employee will end the call with client and second employee will call him again and create the invoice)

I want to select

1. Employee which made the first call
2. Employee which created the invoice
3. Invoice ID
4. Invoice Date

Comment: What is that you have tried? Post the query that you have written and let us know the problem , we can help you.

Comment: @Ahmed Hassan please check ma answer

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your answer...

else pls put a comment. will help you

1. Employee which make the first call

   ```
   select Employee.ID, Employee.Name from Call_Log 
   inner join Employee on Call_Log.EmployeeID = Employee.ID
   where Call_Log.Call_Status = 'ReadyToBuy' /*or some constants which mention the status, whether the customer ready or not to buy*/
   ```
2. Employee which create the invoice

   ```
   select Employee.ID, Employee.Name from Invoic 
   inner join Employee on Invoic.EmployeeID = Employee.ID
   ```
3. Invoice

   ```
   select Invoic.*, Invoic_Details.ProductName from Invoic 
   inner join Invoic_Details on Invoic.ID = Invoic_Details.InvoiceID
   ```
4. Invoice Date

   ```
   select Date from Invoic
   ```

Comment: I need all in one record not single records , Just one query

Answer (score 0):

```
select call_log.employee_id ,invoice.employee_id,invoice.id,invoice.date
from call_log inner join invoice on call_log.id=invoice.call_log_id
where call_status='ReadytoBuy';
```

I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
SELECT t2.NAME
    ,t5.NAME
    ,t3.ID
    ,t3.creation_date
FROM @call_log t1
INNER JOIN @Employee t2 ON t2.employee_id = t1.employee_id
    AND STATUS = 'invoiced'
INNER JOIN @invoice t3 ON t3.call_log_id = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN @call_log t4 ON t1.num_id = t4.num_id
    AND t4.STATUS = 'started_call'
LEFT JOIN @Employee t5 ON t4.employee_id = t5.employee_id
```